# Trying to set cell in LastRow to a value following appendRow

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

As part of a bigger script I'm using the following to append data to my sheet

```
scSsOutputData.forEach(x => 
                       {scSh.appendRow(x);
scSh.getRange(scSh.getLastRow(), headers.ADJUSTMENTS+1).setValue("FORMULA HERE")});
```

The appendRow is working fine but the next line is behaving weird. On the first iteration it does nothing then on the second it puts the value in the row above.

Comment: dont know for sure, but try scSh.getLastRow + 1

Comment: Tried that. No difference except it ended up on the row below

Comment: maybe concat the x with the string and make one append?

Comment: issue is ultimately it will be a formula & I don't think you can concat them to an array

Comment: Try `SpreadsheetApp.flush()` between the two lines inside the `forEach` function. Also maybe you want to consider `setFormula` instead of `setValue`.

Comment: Also it is a good practice to avoid using `appendRow` inside loops. Instead you can avoid the loop and use setValues. And if you want to insert a new row then insert the number of desired rows by sheet.insertRows() and then use setValues to paste all the values without using a for loop. In this way you use only two functions (insertRows and setValues) while in your current code you are using two functions per each iteration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Issues:**

Your current code **appends** a value to a new row by using `appendRow(x)` and then it sets the value of another cell in the same row using `setValue`. This is a very computational expensive method given also the fact that is inside a for loop. Maybe a `SpreadsheetApp.flush()` between the two operations would solve the issue, although your goal is to optimize it even better.

It is a good practice to **avoid** using `appendRow()` inside a for loop.

If you want to create a new row, use `insertRowsAfter(scSh.getLastRow(), scSsOutputData.length)` to create `scSsOutputData.length` number of rows after the last row with content and then use `getRange().setValues()` to insert the desired values.

### **Solutions:**

**First solution:**

```
scSsOutputData.forEach(x => 
                       {
scSh.appendRow(x);
SpreadsheetApp.flush();
scSh.getRange(scSh.getLastRow(), headers.ADJUSTMENTS+1).setValue("FORMULA HERE");
});
```

**Second solution (recommended):**

Transform `scSsOutputData` to a format like that:

```
[
[x,,,"FORMULA HERE"],
[x,,,"FORMULA HERE"],
[x,,,"FORMULA HERE"],
.....
]
```

the commas between `x` and `FORMULA HERE` indicate the columns that you want to skip when pasting values. In the above example you skip 2 columns.

Therefore you could use:

```
scSh.insertRowsAfter(scSh.getLastRow(), scSsOutputData.length);
scSh.getRange(scSh.getLastRow()+1, 1, 1, 2+columns you want to skip in between).setValues(scSsOutputData);
```

In the second solution you use only **two** operations. In the first solution you use **two** operations per `scSsOutputData` element.

Comment: Thanks Marios. Indeed `flush` did the job. I take your point about the use of 'appendRow()` but given I am actually intending on replacing `FORMULA HERE` with an actual format I think I'd have to add more code to perform that. Given that is currently achieved with

`scSsOutputData.forEach(x => 
                       {
scSh.appendRow(x);
SpreadsheetApp.flush();
scSh.getRange(scSh.getLastRow(), headers.ADJUSTMENTS+1).setFormula("=1+2");
});`

Do you not think that would be quicker ultimately? Thanks for all your assistance with this

Comment: P.S. Actually seems to need the `flush` after the last line. Who knows...

Comment: @ChrisBarrett I think it is worth a try but maybe your specific case does not need a lot of optimization.